# Toast not appearing after button click within a fragment?

Tags: android

I have a button which goes to another page when the edittext textfields have been entered correctly. However what I want to do is make a toast appear if the user has not entered in the textfields correctly. The error checking does work, as it prevents the user going to the next page, i.e. if there isn't 16 numbers in cardchecker field or 3 numbers in cvv checker field.

This is for a windows server. I have tried changing after the Toast.makeText(, to `getActivity().getApplicationcontext`, `this` & `getActivity` on its own.

```
public class DonateFragment extends Fragment {
    EditText cardno;
    Button buy;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_donate,container,false);
        final EditText cardcheck1 =(EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cardno);
        final EditText sortcheck1 =(EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sortcode);
        final EditText cvvcheck1 =(EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cvv);
        final EditText amountcheck1 =(EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.amount);
        Button buy = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buy);


            buy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String cardcehcker = cardcheck1.getText().toString();
                    String sortchecker = sortcheck1.getText().toString();
                    String cvvchecker = cvvcheck1.getText().toString();
                    String amountchecker = amountcheck1.getText().toString();
                    if (cardcehcker.trim().length() == 16){
                        if (cardcehcker.trim().length() < 16){
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                            if (sortchecker.trim().length() == 6)
                                if (cvvchecker.trim().length() == 3)
                                    if(amountchecker.trim().length()>0){
                                    {
                                        Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), Donation_thankyou_activity.class);
                                        startActivity(in);
                                    }}}}
            });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I expect a toast to appear if the user has not entered it in correctly, but no toast appears.

Comment: Check your logic in those nested `if`s. How can a number be both equal to 16 and less than 16?

Comment: Issue with your if statement . They are in contradiction with themselves . First you are checking if length is equal to 16 or not and if yes , then again you are checking if length is less then 16 .

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
public class DonateFragment extends Fragment {
    EditText cardno;
    Button buy;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_donate,container,false);
        final EditText cardcheck1 =(EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cardno);
        final EditText sortcheck1 =(EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sortcode);
        final EditText cvvcheck1 =(EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cvv);
        final EditText amountcheck1 =(EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.amount);
        Button buy = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buy);


            buy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String cardcehcker = cardcheck1.getText().toString();
                    String sortchecker = sortcheck1.getText().toString();
                    String cvvchecker = cvvcheck1.getText().toString();
                    String amountchecker = amountcheck1.getText().toString();
                    if (cardcehcker.trim().length() == 16 && sortchecker.trim().length() == 6 && cvvchecker.trim().length() == 3 && amountchecker.trim().length()>0){
                        Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), Donation_thankyou_activity.class);
                        startActivity(in);
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```